# Email Template in PHP

Tags: php, email, templates

I am trying to add paragraph in email template but not getting it done as I get confused because `nl2br` is not working in email template

Should I use `\r\n` and where to write it?

```
'email-message' => $data['mail-message']
```

Comment: what is content-type for email template ?

Comment: 'email-message' => $data['mail-message']
 $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $post = array(
            'amount'        => $currencySymbol.$data['price'],
            'code'          => 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX',
            'email-to'      => $data['mail-to'],
            'email-from'    => $data['mail-from'],
            'link'          => '#',
            'email-message' => $data['mail-message'],
            'store-phone'   =>   Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone'),
            'picture'       => $picture,
        );

Comment: $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $post = array(
            'amount'        => $currencySymbol.$data['price'],
            'code'          => 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX',
            'email-to'      => $data['mail-to'],
            'email-from'    => $data['mail-from'],
            'link'          => '#',
            'email-message' => $data['mail-message'],
            'store-phone'   => Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone'),
            'picture'       => $picture,
        );

Answer (score 0):

There can be reason of `content-type` behind this issue. You need to use a `<br>` if your `content-type` is `text/html`. `content-type header` is must otherwise your e-mail will be interpreted an plain text. In case If you want to use `\n` you should use `content-type: text/plain` but then you will lose any markup. So better to use `content-type` as `text/html` and use `<br>`.

Comment: 'email-message' => $data['mail-message']
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $post = array(
            'amount'        => $currencySymbol.$data['price'],
            'code'          => 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX',
            'email-to'      => $data['mail-to'],
            'email-from'    => $data['mail-from'],
            'link'          => '#',
            'email-message' => $data['mail-message'],
            'store-phone'   => Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone'),
            'picture'       => $picture,
        );